# All ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ are finitely-generated

Tags: ring-theory

The question comes from a problem, which asks to find all prime and maximal ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}] := \{\frac{a}{2^k} : k\in\mathbb{Z} , a\in 2\mathbb{Z}+1 \} $. Well I solved it by assuiming that $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ is a $PID$, but **I didn't succeed to prove that all the ideals are finitely generated** (for those which are finitely generated I already demonstrated that they are generated by one element).

Comment: You want to show that $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ is noetherian. First recall that the integers are noetherian and thus by the Gauss lemma so is the polynomial ring over the integers. Recall that quotient rings of noetherian rings are noetherian. I leave you to find an ideal $I$ such that $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]\cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take some ideal $I \leq \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$. Now consider the following ideal of the integers $J_I \leq \mathbb{Z}$:
$$ J_I = <\{a \in \mathbb{Z} : \exists k \in \mathbb{Z}, \; \; \frac{a}{2^k} \in I \}>.$$
(Here the reason we're taking the ideal generated by this set is because technically according to the definition you gave, we can divide by $2^k$ for some negative $k$.)

Note that $J_I$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$, hence it is generated by an element $a^* \in \mathbb{Z}$. We show that $a^*$ generates $I$ (just multiply by $\frac{1}{2^k}$ for the appropriate $k$). Obviously $a^* \in I$, so $(a^*) \subseteq I$.
On the other hand, take any element $i = \frac{b}{2^k} \in I$. It's Numerator can be written as $ b = a^*z$ for some $z \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence $a^*\frac{z}{2^k} = i$ and thus $I \subseteq (a^*)$.

We conclude that every ideal is generated by one element.